# 151 Mew's using Regidrago VStar's attack

Tags: pokemon

Ok so me and a friend where discussing this but can Mew use Regidrago VStar's Apex Dragon as it's move?

Mew's attack

**Genome Hacking: Choose 1 of your opponent's Active Pokémon's attacks and use it as this attack.**

Regidrago VStar's attack

**Apex Dragon: Choose an attack from a Dragon Pokémon in your discard pile and use it as this attack.**

I feel it should not work unless my opponent has a Dragon Pokémon in there discard pile. But my friend has been using my own discard pile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, Mew may use the attack but the text applies to the player using the attack (so the player using Genome Hacking may only use their own discarded dragon Pokémon’s attacks). Similarly, if you use Lost Mine (sableye) you would need ten in the lost zone yourself to be able to carry out the attack.